# Bulma collapsible not working when using CDN

Tags: bulma

I have included the CSS and JS CDN. I have also tried to use the whole extension CDN and it still wont work. Here is the codepen.

https://codepen.io/firdausai/pen/rNxBLKr?editors=1000

```
<head>

    <!-- Load bulma CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.2/css/bulma.min.css">

<!-- Load bulma accordion CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma-accordion@2.0.1/dist/css/bulma-accordion.min.css">

    <!-- Load fontawesome CDN -->
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card">
    <header class="card-header">
        <p class="card-header-title">
            Card title
        </p>
        <a href="#collapsible-card" data-action="collapse" class="card-header-icon is-hidden-fullscreen" aria-label="more options">
            <span class="icon">
                <i class="fas fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </span>
        </a>
    </header>
    <div id="collapsible-card" class="is-collapsible is-active">
        <div class="card-content">
            <p class="title is-4">
                “There are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one
                errors.”
            </p>
            <p class="subtitle is-5">
                Jeff Atwood
            </p>
        </div>
        <footer class="card-footer">
            <p class="card-footer-item">
                <span>
                    View on <a href="https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/506010907021828096">Twitter</a>
                </span>
            </p>
            <p class="card-footer-item">
                <span>
                    Share on <a href="#">Facebook</a>
                </span>
            </p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
    <script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma-accordion@2.0.1/dist/js/bulma-accordion.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Read [the documentation](https://wikiki.github.io/components/accordion/#javascript), you have to add this line :

```
var accordions = bulmaAccordion.attach(); // accordions now contains an array of all Accordion instances
```

But bulma-accordion has some bugs, and as mentioned in the docs there is a new version with a lot of new functionalities [here](https://github.com/CreativeBulma/bulma-collapsible/), I'm using it and I find it better than bulma-accordion.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I ended up using to bulma collapsible instead of bulma-accordian. I didn't even realize that those two are two different things. I got the collapsible component to work. But i am having trouble animating the collapsible element smoothly when i close it. So when it expands it has a smooth animation. When i close it, it just disappear without any animation. I tried reading the documentation and i didn't find anything related to smooth animation. Though i find the option object might help, but there are no example of its usage. Any tips?

Comment: I didn't have time to look at it, indeed it's not smooth on close.... the strange thing is that in [the documentation' examples](https://demo.creativebulma.net/components/bulma-collapsible/1.0/usage/#accordion) it's pretty smooth....

Answer (score 0):

use under the body section:

```
 <script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma- 
    accordion@2.0.1/dist/js/bulma-accordion.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var accordions = bulmaAccordion.attach()
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).